# ReportingServices: Excel export How to force new sheet?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have report with cover page (disclaimer) normally printed on separate page and on the other pages main data.
Works well when printing, but when exporting the same report to Excel cover page and data are presented on same sheet.
**I need a way to force the cover page to be on separate Excel's sheet.**

I tried everything: page brakes, put disclaimer on the rectangle and set page brake on it - nothing helped...

The report structure looks as follow:
- data table and cover page lie on the List
- cover page is subReport control linked to external report
- below subReport is placed Table control with main data

Any idea how to force new sheets in Excel ?!

Answer (score 1):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/5e381767-4f56-4966-b1b7-b1bfa71feb1a

---

Save BBC 6Music